# Calculating Volume of Reservoir using python and ArcMap10?

Tags: arcmap, raster

I have a raster file with different water depth in each cell. I am using Aster DEM so my resolution of that file is 30m by 30m. Now I want to calculate the total volume in that area by multiplying water depth in each cell by area of the cell and calculating the total. How can i perform this using python and arcmap 10 ? I would be glad to receive your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can carry this out quickly using the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000), either using the ArcMap user interface or a python script (see previous link for the code snippet).

You already know your cell resolution (30m by 30m) and your depth (represented by each cell in the raster), so you simply need to calculate the [volume of each pixel as a rectangular prism](http://www.math.com/tables/geometry/volumes.htm). Make sure your depth measurements are in the same units as your cell resolution and that they do indeed represent the depth from waters' surface (not elevation).

Once you have created your volume raster representing the volume at each pixel, you can use the [Calculate Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m3000000) tool to get the **sum** of values for the entire raster (or a subset by using the area of interest option).